# What are the prospects in synthetic biology, especially in the introduction of biological computers?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, bioinformatics

One of the interesting areas of synthetic biology is the so-called [biological computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_biology#Biological_computers). A biological computer refers to an engineered biological system that can perform computer-like operations. I have read a large number of articles on this topic, and in almost all of them the logic gates are made of DNA or RNA inside bacteria. What are the prospects? For example, are there developments that imply the construction of logic elements and microcircuits directly inside the cell: DNA encodes the necessary proteins that are synthesized and assembled into logic gates and other components in the cell?

Comment: I wonder why people put a minus without any explanation?

Comment: 1 downvote is from me - people aren't obliged to explain why they downvoted. I downvoted because, whilst certainly interesting, your post doesn't ask a question with an objective, fact-based answer. 'What are the prospects' is quite open-ended and will encourage opinion-based answers. If you have a specific quesiton about synthetic biology, I'd encourage you to focus on that. Thanks.

Comment: @user438383 a specific question: are there developments that imply the construction of logic elements and microcircuits directly inside the cell: DNA encodes the necessary proteins that are synthesized and assembled into logic gates and other components in the cell?

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress If you can formulate more specific and less opinion-based questions, I would encourage you to ask them as separate questions, rather than asking them in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the prospects? For example, are there developments that imply the construction of logic elements and microcircuits directly inside the cell: DNA encodes the necessary proteins that are synthesized and assembled into logic gates and other components in the cell?

Yes, there is an entire literature on this called "genetic circuit design", which [Brophy and Voigt 2014](https://www.nature.com/articles/nmeth.2926) introduce nicely. [Xiang *et al.* 2018](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11047-018-9715-9) provides a discussion of developing biological computers. [Karkaria *et al.* 2020](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fbioe.2020.00834/full) provides an excellent overview of what this field has accomplished, what the current challenges are (such as metabolic load and non-orthogonality of parts), and how they might be tackled by having community (distributed) circuits.

For a school assignment I performed a rudimentary citation analysis of the genetic design literature ([Seilis 2020](https://github.com/galenseilis/CPSC706-research-methods/blob/main/final_report.pdf)). While it isn't publication-quality work, and certainly isn't peer-reviewed, you might find some interesting papers are cited there.

In terms of logic gates, you'll find that both unary gates and all sixteen possible binary gates, and many others, have molecular implementations. And in terms of prospects, they could be used for monitoring and control, production of medicine and goods, and literally run molecular experiments, among others. I recall Xie et al. 2013 constructed a circuit that when put in non-cancerous cells did nothing, but when put into HeLa cells would trigger apoptosis.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that computation is possible without every logic gate type. In fact, the minimal set of logic gates requires only a single type-- either NAND or NOR. These are called "universal logic gates", since they can be combined with themselves to produce any other logic gate. In practice this is often very convenient in that it allows for device construction with only one process, rather than many different processes (one per gate type).

Comment: The [functional completeness of certain sets of boolean functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness) is worth mentioning because it motivates the intuitive idea that we could program a system to do whatever we want within the physical limitations of the system.

Comment: One of the physical limitations that prevents us from just using compositions of NAND or NOR everywhere is the non-orthogonality of parts. Unlike in a silica circuit where identical parts would have isolated behaviour, solution chemistry leads to things dispersing  across the cell. To have two independently-acting NAND/NOR gates one would have to implement them using different interactions to prevent undesired behaviour. This is one of the challenges discussed in [Karkaria *et al* 2020](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fbioe.2020.00834/full) among others.